# Syn flood and net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies

Tags: docker

I am trying to configure a Docker container, running tengine on *Ubuntu 14*, to use syncookies. However I am facing some issues.

The host has `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1` enabled and syncookies work directly on the host. But the container on the same host does not use syncookies.

Does anyone know a way of getting the container to use syncookies?

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: I was under the impression that both native and contained processes use host network stack, segregated into namespaces. Thus it's quite odd that global setting `net.ipv4.xxx` somehow doesn't apply to container...

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the default bridge will be missing a lot of customizations you make on the host network interface. Bypass the bridge completely and attach the container directly to the host network (not a good general practice, but your use case is atypical) with a:

```
docker run --network host ...
```

Comment: We ended up doing just that, but using docker-compose `net: "host"`